# How does the CTS tool determines the modules or number of test to be run on any particular android device?

Tags: android, cts, gts

I have executed CTS in 2 different android devices (**Android phone** and **Android TV**), the number of test cases and modules differs for both .
As per my understanding the supported modules and related test are populated .

I wish to know that how the modules and test counts are determined as soon as we start the **"run cts"** in cts-tradefed ??

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that and the only lead I have is that you should compare the archives of the testing packages in those repostiories, relative path is:

```
./out/host/linux-x86/cts/android-cts.zip
```

and respectively, the list:

```
./out/host/linux-x86/cts/android-cts.zip.list
```